# i have a listbox and check box and how can i find the how much check box checked in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to find how much check box is checked by code :

```
 <Grid Width="440" >

<ListBox Name="listBoxZone" ItemsSource="{Binding TheList}"  Background="White" Margin="0,120,2,131">  
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" Content="{Binding StatusName}" Tag="{Binding StatusId}" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment ="Top"   />
             </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

      </Grid>
```

---

Here is my code where i want to find how  much check box is checked ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxZone.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (CheckBoxZone.IsChecked == true )
                        { 


                        }

                    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your approach?

Answer (score 3):

You could add an `IsChecked` property of type `Nullable<bool>` (could be written as `bool?`) to your data item class and two-way bind the [CheckBox.IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked) property:

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckBoxZone" IsChecked={Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay} ... />
```

Now you can simple iterate over all items and check their `IsChecked` state:

```
int numChecked = 0;
foreach (MyItem item in listBoxZone.Items)
{
    if ((bool)item.IsChecked) // cast Nullable<bool> to bool
    {
        numChecked++;
    }
}
```

or with Linq:

```
int numChecked =
    itemsControl.Items.Cast<MyItem>().Count(i => (bool)i.IsChecked);
```

And just a note: why do you use HierarchicalDataTemplate in a ListBox, where [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) would be sufficient?

Comment: @Abhishek If this answer solves your problem, you should consider to accept it. Simply check the accept mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OfType` Method of LINQ

```
int result = 
            listBoxZone.Items.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(i => i.IsChecked == true);
```

I used `OfType` instead of `Cast` because `OfType` will work even if there a single checkbox item or all items are checkboxes.

In case of `Cast` it will give error if even a single item is not checkbox.

Comment: In my answer i'm assuming that all items are of the (same) type `MyItem`, hence `Cast<>` is fully ok. I'm not iterating over CheckBoxes, since these are neither the item type, nor the item container type. Here a CheckBox is "hidden" in the DataTemplate and not easily accessible by application code. Your `result` will always be zero.

Comment: `Cast<>` is even better than `OfType<>` since it provides a fail-fast error detection if an item is added that is mistakenly not a `MyItem`.